# How to echo part of php from another file?

Tags: php, wordpress, file, echo

I have a WordPress page that is build out of different PHP files. In one the files there is a PHP Script that calculates the deadline when the application closes. I would like to echo this at the bottom of my page, but that's part of a different file.

What am i doing wrong?

**File 1:**

```
    <?php $deadline = {
                        $now = time();
                        $dueDate = get_field('due_date');
                        $dueDate = strtotime($dueDate);
                        $datediff = $dueDate - $now;
                        $daysLeft = floor($datediff/(60*60*24))+1;
                        $daysLeft = intval($daysLeft);
                        ?>
                        <?php if($daysLeft == 0) {
                            echo 'Last day';
                        } elseif($daysLeft < 0) {
                            echo 'Deadline passed';
                        } elseif($daysLeft == 1) {
                            echo $daysLeft.' days left';
                        } else {
                            echo $daysLeft.' days left';
                        }
                    }?>
```

**File 2:**

```
  <?php 
      include('/../content-challenge.php'); 
      echo $deadline; 
  ?>
```

**Note:** as you see the file where file 2 points at is in a dir above the file it needs to be echoed in.

Comment: You have completly wrong syntax. Why you open `{` after `$deadline` ? Whats the idea of it? Thats nothing else than a syntax error. What do you want `$deadline` to be? A function? A array?

Answer (score 0):

File 1.

```
<?php 

    function deadline() {

        $now = time();
        $dueDate = get_field( 'due_date' );
        $dueDate = strtotime( $dueDate );
        $datediff = $dueDate - $now;
        $daysLeft = floor( $datediff / ( 60*60*24 ) )+1;
        $daysLeft = intval( $daysLeft );

        if( $daysLeft == 0 ) {

            echo 'Last day';

        }elseif( $daysLeft < 0 ) {

            echo 'Deadline passed';

        }elseif( $daysLeft == 1 ) {

            echo $daysLeft.' days left';

        }else {

            echo $daysLeft.' days left';
        }

    } 
?>
```

File 2.

If the function is defined in functions.php

```
<?php deadline(); ?>
```

or if is defined in any other file then you must include this file like you did (be sure that path is good)

```
<?php

  include('/../content-challenge.php');

  deadline();

?>
```

Comment: I think `echo $now = time();` is intended to be `$now = time();`.